# Weird loss pattern when using two losses in caffe

Tags: deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I am training a CNN in caffe and receive following weird loss pattern:

```
I0425 16:38:58.305482 23335 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #0: loss = nan (* 1 = nan loss)
I0425 16:38:58.305524 23335 solver.cpp:398]     Test net output #1: loss_intermediate = inf (* 1 = inf loss)
I0425 16:38:59.235857 23335 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 0 (-4.2039e-45 iter/s, 20.0094s/50 iters), loss = 18284.4
I0425 16:38:59.235926 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 18274.9 (* 1 = 18274.9 loss)
I0425 16:38:59.235942 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss_intermediate = 9.46859 (* 1 = 9.46859 loss)
I0425 16:38:59.235955 23335 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 0, lr = 1e-06
I0425 16:39:39.330327 23335 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 50 (1.24704 iter/s, 40.0948s/50 iters), loss = 121737
I0425 16:39:39.330410 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 569.695 (* 1 = 569.695 loss)
I0425 16:39:39.330425 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss_intermediate = 121168 (* 1 = 121168 loss)
I0425 16:39:39.330433 23335 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 50, lr = 1e-06
I0425 16:40:19.372197 23335 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 100 (1.24868 iter/s, 40.0421s/50 iters), loss = 34088.4
I0425 16:40:19.372268 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 369.577 (* 1 = 369.577 loss)
I0425 16:40:19.372283 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss_intermediate = 33718.8 (* 1 = 33718.8 loss)
I0425 16:40:19.372292 23335 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 100, lr = 1e-06
I0425 16:40:59.501541 23335 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 150 (1.24596 iter/s, 40.1297s/50 iters), loss = 21599.6
I0425 16:40:59.501606 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 478.262 (* 1 = 478.262 loss)
I0425 16:40:59.501621 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss_intermediate = 21121.3 (* 1 = 21121.3 loss)
...
I0425 17:09:01.895849 23335 solver.cpp:219] Iteration 2200 (1.24823 iter/s, 40.0568s/50 iters), loss = 581.874
I0425 17:09:01.895912 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #0: loss = 532.049 (* 1 = 532.049 loss)
I0425 17:09:01.895926 23335 solver.cpp:238]     Train net output #1: loss_intermediate = 49.8377 (* 1 = 49.8377 loss)
I0425 17:09:01.895936 23335 sgd_solver.cpp:105] Iteration 2200, lr = 1e-06
```

FYI: My Network consists of basically two stages therefore I have two losses. The first stage can be seen as a *coarse* stage and the second one is an *upsampling* stage of the *coarse* stage.

My question is: Is this a typical loss pattern? First the *loss* value is high and the *intermediate_loss* is low for the first iteration and then it basically turns around in the next iterations so the *loss* is lower and the *intermediate_loss* is higher. In the end only the *intermediate_loss* converges.

Comment: Are you using BatchNorm layers?

Comment: Yes! But I do set `global_stats` false when training and true when testing @Shai Maybe I should first train the first network stage and then set all lr_param to 0 of the first stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"typical" isn't really an applicable term.  There is such a variety of models and topologies that you can find many examples of strange loss progressions.

In your case, the intermediate loss may well start out low because it "doesn't know any better" yet.  As the latter layers become trained enough to give reliable feedback to the intermediate layers, *then* it begins learning enough to have serious mistakes.

The final loss computation is in direct contact with ground truth; it learns from the first iteration, so it has a more understandable progression from high loss to low.